# Mifare Plus Security Level 2 support in Android

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to communicate with **Mifare Plus** card in **security level 2** using android application.

I am able to get **nfcA** object in **android.**

When I call transceive I get a **Tag lost exception**.

I searched around and found somewhere that Mifare Plus needs more power for AES operations. So I tried placing the card as close as possible to my device and around the center.

It took me some time but I was able to **find a sweet spot** and my transceive call was passing. However it failed in second transceive call (2nd pass in AES authentication). Few more tries and it cleared that. **AES authentication was successful!**

However, after that I am failing at **Mifare Authentication**.

I tried placing card at different positions but it is still not passing. I keep getting **tag lost exception**. Stangely, once I also got **IO exception** at the same place. (Mifare Authentication)

I also tried with **setTimeout**() but no help.

**Is it the limitation of Android/Device or I am missing something? Any help or information would mean a lot. Thanks!**

PS. The device I am using **comes with NXP chipset/Firmware**, so I am guessing device should support SL2 as well. Am I right? Thanks again!